# UV unwrapping turns the uvmap model inside out

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

When I unwrap this the legs point outwards:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mlcv.png

I added some white and red colors to the pic to indicate where the verts ended up.

Here is a blend example:
https://www114.zippyshare.com/v/NxgNqXtR/file.html

How to get it to unwrap correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the option *Fill Holes* turned on in the Unwrap settings which gives the undesired result in this case.

Turning it off will unwrap your model correctly.

[image]

[image]